# How can I access OptionValue plugin configuration values in Java

Tags: rundeck

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#configuring says

> To configure your plugin you can add configuration values to either the framework or project scope.
>
> Framework scope property definition in framework.properties
>
> > framework.plugin.OptionValues.[your_plugin_name].[property]=value
>
> Project scope property definition in project.properties
>
> > project.plugin.OptionValues.[your_plugin_name].[property]=value

I have added a project property which I would expect to find someplace in config. For instance, if the keys from project.properties were available, this code should create them as options:

```
@Override
public List<OptionValue> getOptionValues(Map config) {
    List<OptionValue> optionValues = new ArrayList<OptionValue>();
    Iterator keys = config.keySet().iterator();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next().toString();
        optionValues.add(new StringOptionValue(key, key));
    }
    optionValues.add(new StringOptionValue("stub", "stub'));
    return optionValues;
}
```

My project properties looks like

```
project.disable.executions=false
project.disable.schedule=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.batch=500
project.execution.history.cleanup.enabled=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.days=60
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.minimum=50
project.execution.history.cleanup.schedule=0 0 0 1/1 * ? *
project.jobs.gui.groupExpandLevel=1
project.name=Nodeless
project.output.allowUnsanitized=false
project.plugin.OptionValues.MyOptionProvider.endpoint=https\://example.com/rest
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
project.ssh-command-timeout=0
project.ssh-connect-timeout=0
project.ssh-keypath=/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
resources.source.1.type=local
service.FileCopier.default.provider=jsch-scp
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=jsch-ssh
```

How do I access the plugn configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is to use Plugin Annotations:

```
@PluginProperty(title = "Web service endpoint", description = "Server URL and path", required = true, scope=PropertyScope.Project)
private String endpoint;
```